# Symfony 6 - Cannot autowire argument Entity of Controller

Tags: symfony

I am trying to remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle from composer, however, when I do, I get the error above in my Controllers that have parameterized routes. Not finding the correct answer for a replacement?

Her is an example controller snippet.

```
namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Entity\Ticket;
    use App\Form\TicketType;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    
    #[Route('/admin/ticket')]
    
    class TicketController extends AbstractController
    {
        #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_ticket_show', methods: ['GET'])]
        public function show(Ticket $ticket): Response
        {
            return $this->render('ticket/show.html.twig', [
                'ticket' => $ticket,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide Ticket class and TicketRepository class code

Comment: The docs and examples are [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#automatically-fetching-objects-entityvalueresolver).  I know it sounds silly but you are sure that you are using 6.2 since the new entity resolver was just introduced?  The functionality used to be in the extra bundle.  The only thing I see different is your class route prefix.  Might try following the example exactly.  Might confirm your route with `bin/console debug:router app_ticket_show`.  Maybe update your question with the relevant portion of the error message.

Comment: I am not using 6.2, I am on Symfony 6.0.19. For now, I am going to continue with the sensio/framwork-extra bundle, but I'll work on upgrading the 6.2 and see if I can get it working. Thanks All!